# Are these subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to know whether the following are subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$

$$S = \{(2a-1,4a-2)\mid a\in \mathbb{C}\}$$
$$U = \{(2a-1,4a-2)\mid a\in \mathbb{R}\}$$
$$T = \{(2a+3b,4a-c)\mid a,b,c\in \mathbb{C}\}$$
$$V = \{(a-1,a-b)\mid a,b\in \mathbb{C}\}$$

I got that S,T and V are subspaces but U is not due to scalar multiplication by $i$.

Am I correct?

Comment: Except $T$, they're *affine* subspaces, not *vector* subspaces.

Comment: @Bernard if you don't mind me asking, why did you remove the example $\{(2a-1,4a-2)|a\in\mathbb{C}\}$ that OP originally had? also, I believe all except $\{(2a-1,4a-2)|a\in\mathbb{R}\}$ are vector subspaces. for instance, $\{(a-1,a-b)|a,b\in\mathbb{C}\}=\mathbb{C}^2$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom: But it is `S`, which is still there! What's the problem?

Comment: @Bernard oh, I think there was a slight notational confusion :) ... the set I wrote has $a$ ranging over $\mathbb{C}$, while the set you denote $S$ has $a$ ranging over $\mathbb{R}$. OP originally had both

Comment: There were 4 examples? Was it what the O.P. denotes $U$?

Comment: @Bernard indeed, OP had the three sets you have there, along with the set $\{(2a-1,4a-2)|a\in\mathbb{C}\}$ (you can check the edit history to see). I think you just missed that those two were different, as they look quite similar at first glance. :) I'm going to roll back your edit, I hope that's alright

Comment: Initially, I just wanted to make the code  display correctly, replacing `|` with `\mid` which has the right spacing.

Comment: @Bernard no worries, good thinking; I've just replaced all the instances of `|` with `\mid`, hopefully that's alright

Comment: Fine, thank you! (and a happy new year!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, $U$ is not a complex vector space, since it is stable with respect to multiplication by $i$. But you should provide a concrete example. For instance, $(1,2)\in U$, but $(i,2i)\notin U$.

All others are complex vector subspaces.